# rails7 app is not accessible from browser on local machine when running in container locally

Tags: ruby, docker, dockerfile, ruby-on-rails-7, colima

I have rails7 app running in container fine. but I cant access it from 'outside' seems like docker/colima is not forwarding port, but other apps (sinatra) on the same settings works fine.

`docker run -d -p 5678:5678 rails7_docker:v1`

```
...
EXPOSE 5678
RUN rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 5678
```

```sh
docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS               NAMES
5e1b388ef17c   5f7b5a1d199d   "/bin/sh -c 'rails s…"   12 minutes ago   Up 12 minutes   443/tcp, 5678/tcp   xenodochial_austin
❯ docker exec -it xenodochial_austin bash
root@144666e66c2c:/home/rails/agent# curl http://localhost:5678/
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
```

I have no idea where to look for solution or how to debug, as other projects works fine but this not. It's default rails new project with no modifications.
ruby - 3+
rails7, os x, docker + colima, intel mac.

if you need any more details, please ask.

Comment: A `RUN` command runs while the image is building, which isn't what you want for `rails server`.  Does the image have a `CMD`?  How are you running the image?  (What you're describing sounds like the `-b 0.0.0.0` option isn't taking effect.)

Comment: You haven't posted enough information. What is your container entrypoint, and why do you think you have a server on that particular port?

Answer (score -1):

If you use `--network="host"`, it should work.

Comment: it is working now and I have o idea why it was not working... I tried everything, from restarting computer to reinstalling docker and colima